# Unity match 3 style game matching process with canvas images

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, canvas

I am creating a game like bejeweled game. I am using canvas and my game objects are canvas images. My objects are in the grid correctly when the game started but I don't know how can I match and Destroy the same type objects(images).

What kind of code blocks I can use for this?

Here is structure:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DynamicGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public int col, row;
    public Image[] prefabs = new Image[6];
    private Image image;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        RectTransform parent = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        GridLayoutGroup grid = gameObject.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup> ();

        grid.cellSize = new Vector2 (parent.rect.width / col, parent.rect.height / row);   //grid cell size (ex: 4x4 - 3x5 etc.)

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {   //fill the rows
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {   //fill the columns
                int num = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, prefabs.Length);   //select a random number (from 0 to 6 each numbers for each different jewel images)
                image = (Image)Instantiate (prefabs[num]);   //create the randomly seleceted image
                image.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried multidimensional Image array Image[i,j] to keep the images instead of image variable but I got error. If I can keep the images in multidimensional array maybe I can compare with neighbors with for loops. Do you have any better idea ?

Comment: Try using a multidimensional int array for your logic rather than an Image one. For the display, just match the numbers with the images

Comment: I tried it but how can I match the numbers with images?